# Areas of rectangles under $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus

In my calculus class, we were posed the following two-part problem:

a: Maximise the area of a rectangle with vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(x_0,f(x_0))$ when $f(x):=e^{-x^2}$ and $x_0>0$.

This problem was simple, you take the derivative and find the extrema. Obviously the area function is $A(x)=xe^{-x^2}$. Then some basic calculus:

$$\frac{dA}{dx}=xe^{-x^2}$$
$$=e^{-x^2}-2x^2e^{-x^2}$$
$$=e^{-x^2}(1-2x^2)$$
$$0=1-2x_0^2$$
$$x_0=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$A(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{e}}$$
Now that problem was fine, nothing wrong with it, and my teacher agreed with the answer. The comes part b.

b: Given that $A(x)$ can be expressed as $A(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}$, find $\lim_{x\to\infty}{A(x)}$. Give a geometric interpretation of this answer.

Now, this limit obviously equals $\frac{1}{2}$. My problem is with "Give a geometric interpretation of the answer". Because I feel like this area is obviously wrong. Taking the limit of both functions, you get $\frac{1}{2}$ for the given area function, but zero for the one that makes sense. My teacher is saying that it uses math we’ll learn in the next few chapters, but I can’t imagine we’d learn anything in an elementary calculus class that would suggest something like this. Am I crazy or is my teacher wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the function $A(x)$ in part (b) has anything to do with the area of any rectangle? It was *you* that introduced the "$A(x)$" notation in part (a), not the problem statement itself.

Comment: @MPW My teacher seemed to believe so, but I have a feeling she wasn't the one who made the problem set. If you want to see the exact wording of the original problem, you can see it [here](https://imgur.com/a/3HSu73l)

Comment: @Snacc well there's your problem.  It is specifically talking about the value of $ b $ you found in part (a).  Not claiming that it is an identity for all $ x > 0 $

Comment: I considered that possibility, but there are two problems with it. Firstly, that identity doesn't even work for the value found in part (a), and secondly, that would be asking people to take the limit of a constant, which makes no sense. (Even if you could do that, the idea of a "geometric interpretation" would remain meaningless)

Comment: Those two parts do not seem to fit together at all! Your teacher is wrong somewhere.

Comment: It makes no sense for me either. Note that in the pb there is an $\frac 12$ factor, so $A(b)$ is not negative, but nevertheless I don't see how this $A(b)$ is related to first part.

Comment: Please stop saying things you don't actually mean: $\frac{dA}{dx}\ne xe^{-x^2} \ne e^{-x^2}-2x^2e^{-x^2}$. It is true that the LH and RH sides of that are equal. But neither is equat to the expression in the middle. "=" does not mean "these are related in some general fashion".

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think this is just the $\frac{d}{dx}$ report missing.